# Generating all the covering substrings of a string

Tags: string, substring, sequences

How do you the following: given a string, generate all the possible ways to parse that string into substrings (time is important, space dont' care). 
For example, given the string ABCD, I need to generate:

```
ABCD

A BCD

A BC D

A B CD

AB CD

AB C D

ABC D

A B C D
```

Probably a recursive solution, but I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python:

```
def splitstring(s):
  result = [s]
  for i in range(1, len(s)):
    result.extend('%s %s' % (s[:i], x) for x in splitstring(s[i:]))
  return result
```

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot. I reimplemented it in Perl successfully

Answer (score 4):

Another solution in Python, without recursion:

```
def substrings(s):
    for k in xrange(1, len(s)+1):
        for i in xrange(len(s)-k+1):
            yield s[i:i+k]
```

so that

```
>>> print list(substrings("ABCD"))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'ABC', 'BCD', 'ABCD']
```

Comment: Thank you! For Python3 just replace xrange to range and everything works!.

Answer (score 0):

To get a particular split:

- First, decide at which indices to split;
- Then, split the string at the given indices.

For a string of length `n`, a given set of split indices is an element of the `powerset` of `{1, ..., n}`.

In python:

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def pairs(seq, end):
    "pairs([13,23,33], 55) --> (0,13) (13,23) (23,33) (33,55)"
    return zip(chain((0,), seq), chain(seq, (end,)))

def allsplits(s):
    "allsplits('abc') --> ['abc'] ['a', 'bc'] ['ab', 'c'] ['a', 'b', 'c']"
    for split_indices in powerset(range(1,len(s))):
        yield [s[i:j] for i,j in pairs(split_indices, len(s))]

print(list( allsplits('abcd') ))
# [['abcd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['ab', 'cd'], ['abc', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```